# Google + Button on prettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prettyphoto

I'm currently trying to implement a Google + button inside of a lightbox produced by [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/).

As you can see in their demo, there is a Facebook Like and Twitter button. I've tried all methods with [Google +1 Button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/?hl=en). And have gotten no where. I think it has something to do with it being dynamically added.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks.